# Facebook "out of office" app

Tags: facebook, message

I’d like to implement an “out of office” app for Facebook messages but it doesn’t seem technically possible. The idea is simple, let the user define some dates they won’t be reading Facebook messages (i.e.: they're off-line camping) so that when they get a new message we can notify the friend/sender they won’t be able to respond quickly.

I’ve been reading Facebook’s API and, although I [can read user’s messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/) with proper authorization (`read_mailbox`), I cannot send messages on their behalf.

A workaround would be to get the email address of the sender, and answer with a plan email instead of a Facebook message. But getting the sender's email also requires extended permissions on a per user basis.

I could present the `Send Dialog`, but logically we want this to work automatically without any user interaction. Also, we could post a private status only visible to the sender, but that doesn’t seem very effective.

This is where I hit the wall. Can you think of a way to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* email to `username@facebook.com` (getting the username from the user id does not require any permissions) – but Facebook’s policies forbid apps from using that in general, because they say these addresses are intended for user-to-user communication.

You could make a point saying, that this *was* essentially user-to-user communication – **but use at own risk.** You’re app may be blocked if there’s spam complaints or if Facebook sees you sending a massive amount of messages this way.